# "Give someone trouble" — what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I saw the usage in a translated novel, in which a boy's parents died in an earthquake, and as soon as he knew that both his parents were dead, the boy's immediate reaction was that now he was free and "nobody would give him trouble any more".

What does it imply? Does it mean that no one could ever find fault with things that he does? or that the boy was glad he would never get punished or told off by his parents?

Comment: I can see that you understand what the phrase means. What it implies, however, is something you can understand only by reading the book. The description of the boy's relationship with his parents is the key.

Comment: @Irene I couldn't find any definition for the phrase so I was a bit sceptical about my interpretation, but now I'm glad at least I understand the phrase correctly. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

To give trouble is to bother, hassle or misbehave. A similar phrase would be "...trouble out of..." like this: (double negative intended because of the dialect) "I don't want no trouble out of you" or "Boys, don't you give your momma no trouble while I'm gone."